# Will Windows and Linux installation be more stable without bootloader

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I have a laptop with one SSD disk (and no place for another one) that originally came with Windows 10. It has UEFI and RST as default (which I changed to AHCI). Once, I installed Ubuntu next to it, but after some Windows update Microsoft system got rid of the bootloader, and Ubuntu was damaged, and the setting returned to RST. Now I want to have Ubuntu on my computer once again. I changed RST to AHCI by changing the register and UEFI settings (AHCI was very hidden in the UEFI as it is probably not recommended). I reinstalled Ubuntu and it looks fine, but I have no bootloader. I am wondering, if I don't install the bootloader, maybe I will have lesser chance that my Windows damages Ubuntu again? Maybe it will be more stable that way? Should I install the bootloader? I can access mu Ubuntu by boot menu after going to Windows recovery settings. I will use Ubuntu every day. Another question I have is: do you think it will work this time, and will I be able to keep Ubuntu after each Windows update?

Comment: If you can boot fine then I would not install a bootloader if you don't need one.

Comment: "*[W]ill I be able to keep Ubuntu after each Windows update?*" Sometimes yes, sometimes no. That lack of control is the #1 disadvantage to dual-booting.

Comment: Would placing one OS or the other as a VM be possible?

Comment: @user535733 So I will have less control with dual-booting? Why?

Comment: That's a question that any Search Engine would be happy to answer for you.

Comment: @crip659 I would like to have a real Linux, not a VM as I use it a lot and it was sometimes slow (on the other computer which should be fast). I could consider installing Windows as a VM, as it not that important. I added my digital license to Microsoft account. If i delete Windows, will I be able to have a VM instead of it? How will Microsoft know I deleted my Windows?

Comment: Windows can be weird with their license.  I suggest searching for using Windows as a VM on a computer it is licensed for.

Comment: When a Windows update messes with the Ubuntu bootloader (AKA grub) the easiest thing to do is to boot from a Live Uuntu USB using the try Ubuntu option and install and run the "Boot-Repair" program. Then click on the "Recommended Repair" button. This will fix grub. There is no need to install Ubuntu again and again.

Answer (score 0):

If you can boot Ubuntu without installing a bootloader, then it's not necessary to mess with installing one, furthermore if you decide to install a bootloader anyway after the fact you can still install it by running the recommended repair in the Boot-Repair program. You can install Boot-Repair in a live session of the same Ubuntu live USB that you used to install Ubuntu.